# What is the best way to catch error on promise and why?

Tags: javascript

I have two code examples for catching promise error. What is better way and why is that so?

I have this code with .catch()

```
Message.receive($scope.reference).then(function (response) {
  // on success
}).catch(function (error) {
  // on error
});
```

Also I have this code, without .catch()

```
Message.receive($scope.reference).then(function (response) {
   // on success
}, function (error) {
   // on error
});
```

Comment: Who keeps voting to close this as "opinion based"? There is a semantic difference between the two code snippets, as explained by deceze's answer below.

Comment: [why option 2 is not the way to catch the errors with promises](https://bytearcher.com/articles/using-promise-then-callback-callback-misses-errors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.then(success, error)` executes one or the other callback based on whether `foo` raised an error or not. If `success` raises an error, you'll get an uncaught error, unless you chain another `.catch`.

`foo.then(success).catch(error)` catches any error raised by `foo` ***or `success`***. If `foo` raises an error, `success` is skipped.

It's not which is better, it depends on what error handling chain you want to establish.

Comment: try / catch is really expensive ,and its always good to pass errors in call backs(First args,preferably).Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Shubh What does any of that have to do with the question or answer?

Comment: The best way to catch errors?? @melpomene ,is it callback or catch?

Comment: @Shubh 1) It doesn't have to be a thrown exception, it could simply be a *rejected promise*. 2) Using callbacks of the `(err, data)` style is what was used before promises really existed. If you use this style with promises, you're rather missing the point.

Comment: @Shubh If you have a different question, ask it as a new question. This has nothing to do with OP's code.

Comment: I had a doubt which got cleared by deceze @melpomene

Comment: So, to sum this up, ```foo.then(success).catch(error)``` can catch more errors then ```foo.then(success, error)```. Is this statement correct? Because I want to catch any exception and display error message.

Comment: @Veselin Yes, that's correct. But that's not automatically "better", since you may in fact want `foo.then(success, error).catch(ultimateError)`, depending on how you want to handle *which* error.